# How can I use GLUT with CUDA on MACOSX?

Tags: c, opengl, macos, cuda, glut

I'm having problems compiling a CUDA program that uses GLUT on MacOsX. Here is the command line I use to compile the source:

nvcc main.c -o main -Xlinker "-L/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Libraries -lGL -lGLU" "-L/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework"

And here is the errors I get:

Undefined symbols:
  "_glutInitWindowSize", referenced from:
      _main in tmpxft_00001612_00000000-1_main.o
  "_glutInitWindowPosition", referenced from:
      _main in tmpxft_00001612_00000000-1_main.o
  "_glutDisplayFunc", referenced from:
      _main in tmpxft_00001612_00000000-1_main.o
  "_glutInitDisplayMode", referenced from:
      _main in tmpxft_00001612_00000000-1_main.o
  "_glutCreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in tmpxft_00001612_00000000-1_main.o
  "_glutMainLoop", referenced from:
      _main in tmpxft_00001612_00000000-1_main.o
  "_glutInit", referenced from:
      _main in tmpxft_00001612_00000000-1_main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I am aware that I haven't specified any lib for GLUT but I just can't find it! Does anybody know where it is? By the way, there doesn't seem to be a way to use the GLUT.framework when compiling with nvcc.

Thanks a lot,

omegatai

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you probably already have your answer, but for future reference, you can just use

```
-Xlinker -framework,OpenGL,-framework,GLUT
```

instead of the whole

```
-L/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Libraries -lGL -lGLU
```

when working with nvcc. Source: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=163995

Comment: Yeah, this is what worked for me. I didn't think Xlinker would work for nvcc, but I guess it works in parallel with gcc, so yeah. Thanks a lot everyone and sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/glut/index.html

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. What I needed was just:

```
-framework GLUT -framework openGL -lGLEW
```